# Spring data jpa, Native Query, returned wrong field types

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have following native query method in my repository:

```
@Query(value="SELECT appSub.ApplicationFormId as appFormId, appSub.profileId as profileId, "
                + "p.CASId as profileCASId, ps.programId as programId FROM [unicas_config].[dbo].ApplicationFormEarlyDecisionConfig appFormED "
                + "INNER JOIN [unicas_ux].[dbo].ApplicationSubmission appSub ON appFormED.ApplicationFormId = appSub.applicationFormId "
                + "INNER JOIN [unicas_ux].[dbo].Profile p ON appSub.profileId = p.id "
                + "INNER JOIN [unicas_ux].[dbo].ProgramSelected ps ON p.id=ps.ProfileId AND appSub.applicationFormId = ps.instanceId "
                + "WHERE appFormED.EarlyDecisionVerdictDate >=:fromDate AND appFormED.EarlyDecisionVerdictDate <:toDate "
                + "AND appSub.EarlyDecisionStatus='Applied Early Decision' "
                + "AND appSub.ApplicationStatus='Received' "
                + "AND ps.IsPaid =1 "
                + "ORDER BY appSub.ApplicationFormId",nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> getAllEarlyDecisionApplicantsWithPaidProgramsOnVerdictDate(@Param("fromDate") Date fromDate, @Param("toDate") Date toDate);
```

Now, I want to map the returned result:

```
long appFormId = (Long)obj[0]
long profileId = (Long)obj[1]
long programId = (Long)obj[3]
```

When I am doing that, I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long` as Hibernate consider these ids of `Integer` type instead of `Long`.

Please, tell me how could I programatically tell Hibernate to return proper type.

Comment: I don't think it's got much to do with Hibernate. The JDBC driver will return Java types corresponding to the column type in the database. Why can't you just use a Java Integer?

Comment: @AlanHay. Yea, you wright. I see that column types in the DB are of Int type, even the entity IDs are of long type. That is why I am getting Integer instead of long.

Answer (score 1):

To be on the safe side, I always cast numeric types to `Number` and then get the value of desired type from it, as JDBC driver can return `Integer`, `Long`, `BigDecimal`, etc. depending on the type of the database column:

```
((Number) obj[0]).longValue()
```

Of course, don't forget to check for `null` if column is nullable.